# android: what's this slider bar called and how to implement it?

Tags: android, user-interface, slider, uinavigationbar

This may be a dumb question but could anyone please tell me what this slider (highlighted in yellow) called in Android? Is it a navigation bar?[image]

I want to implement the same slider in my app, could anyone please let me know if there's any sample I can refer to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the part you highlighted, it doesn't have any particular name, it's just some view with selector background.

As for the mechanism itself (pulling view to reveal another), it is [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html). Note that it has been deprecated in API 17, probably this UI pattern is not encouraged anymore.

Comment: great, SlidingDrawer is the functionality I was asking for! Thank you very much!