# What's this vertically sliding view pattern and where's an example of implementing it in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, google-maps-android-api-2

I'd like to implement a sliding view that appears as a banner at the bottom of my map activity and can then be dragged upwards to fill the whole view. This pattern can be found in Google Maps for Android to display information when a marker is clicked. I have an image from Google Maps that outline's what I am looking for but unfortunately don't have the reputation to post it.

The use case is: clicking a marker displays the top of the sliding view at the bottom of the activity. This view can be dragged up the screen to display more information in that location.

A Navigation Drawer is not what I'm after. They slide horizontally from the left or right edge of the the screen. I need the view to slide vertically form the bottom of the screen.

I've seen [SlidingDrawing](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) which was deprecated in API 17 so assume there is now a modern approach to implementing this. Our minimum SDK is Gingerbread (API 10) so am in need of a backwards compatible solution.

I've found existing question on this topic, but none that answer the question.

[android: what's this slider bar called and how to implement it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16450562/android-whats-this-slider-bar-called-and-how-to-implement-it) Pointed me to [SlidingDrawing](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) which I outlined my concerns for above.

[Vertical sliding menu in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452938/vertical-sliding-menu-in-android). Provides a Navigation Slider as the solution.

Comment: https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Comment: Thanks @eee. That is exactly what I was looking for.. no, really... the exact page. I knew I'd seen a solution a while ago but had forgotten what it was. The screenshots of Elon Musk jogged my memory.